# Use Twig variable in include path

Tags: include, twig

I want to use a Twig variable in a include line, but it isn't working:
`{% include 'folder/{{ component }}.twig' %}`

I get the error:
`Unable to find template "folder/{{ component }}.twig"`

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just found the answer here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twig-users/zfnxC16gHx0

The correct syntax is:
`{% include 'folder/' ~ component ~ '.twig' %}`